# Logstash indexing twice when input from file

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

When Logstash indexes from a log file, whenever there is a new log event, it indexes it along with the previous logs in the log file to the elasticsearch index. How to make it configurable so it indexes only the new log events?
P.S The start_position is not set which defaults to end.

Comment: Is the `.sincedb` file being created? Check if the file exists and if it has any contents.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your **sincedb**-file first. ($HOME/.sincedb) It should keep offset after every parsing.
- Make sure you *don't have* **sincedb_path** set to **/dev/null**
- Make sure you *don't have* **start_position** set to **"beginning"**

Comment: This would apply if he would restart his instance before each log, but it doesn't sound like that is the case